# Partitions by null values with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `NewTable` (
    `IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`  int(11) NOT NULL ,
    `PROPERTY_1836`  int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `DESCRIPTION_1836`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `PROPERTY_1837`  int(11) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    `DESCRIPTION_1837`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `PROPERTY_1838`  decimal(18,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `DESCRIPTION_1838`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `PROPERTY_3139`  int(11) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    `DESCRIPTION_3139`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `PROPERTY_3173`  decimal(18,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `DESCRIPTION_3173`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`),
    INDEX `ix_perf_b_iblock_element_pr_1` (`PROPERTY_1837`) USING BTREE ,
    INDEX `ix_perf_b_iblock_element_pr_2` (`PROPERTY_1836`) USING BTREE ,
    INDEX `ix_perf_b_iblock_element_pr_3` (`PROPERTY_3139`) USING BTREE 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=cp1251 COLLATE=cp1251_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

And a query with a condition:

```
WHERE PROPERTY_3139 IS NULL
```

I can't change a table or a query. But I know, if I'll split a table into 2 partitions - queries selecting only nullable values will work much faster.

What kind of trick can I use to do this? NULL and NOT NULL is not a range and I can't use it as a list of values.

Comment: If you can't change the table, how do you expect to add partitions?

Comment: I apologize for the inaccuracy. I can't change a structure of a table. But partitioning is not affects any changes for the queries.

Comment: Why the minus for the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote the question.  But a question that says "I can't change a table or a query" doesn't leave many options for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARTITION` *probably* won't help.

`NULL` is a separate value in an INDEX.  Think of NULLs as being stored in the INDEX before all the other values.  Hence, `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` can be treated as a 'range' for optimization purposes.

However...  If more than 20% (10%-30%, depending on the phase of the moon) of a table is in the desired range, the optimizer will decide that it is faster to do a full table scan instead of bouncing back and forth between the INDEX and the Data.

Back to my *probably*...

- If a small number of rows have NULL, the index will do just fine; PARTITIONing won't help much.
- If a medium number of rows have NULL, then PARTITIONing could help noticeably.
- If most rows have NULL, the a full table scan is almost as good as scanning all of one PARTITION.

Note:  You cannot PARTITION on more than one column.  So, if you PARTITION on `PROPERTY_3139`, the rest of the properties will be out of luck.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer. Your "probably" made me think that is more reasonable to rewrite code, which generates that query. Because rows with Null values for this property more.

Comment: Does your WHERE clause have _only_ the test for one column being NULL?  Is it a performance problem now?  Or is the table going to grow a lot?  What percentage of the table has NULL?  If it is worth pursuing further, start a new question with the focus on the answers to these questions.

Comment: It's 96% of rows with NULL values (total 393940 rows). The query generated by CMS, joining this table with another. So, I think it will be much effective to rewrite php code. Separate it into two queries - first one will select ID's for needed table, second one will get detailed info.